# Attaching and Updating with DateTime properties

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 5 with the a DbContext.

In my scenario I am trying to update an existing entity and persist the changes to the database. Amongst other properties, the entity has a 'LastUpdated' property which is a DateTime.

My entities are POCO entities and my context inherits from DbContext.

Here is my code:

```
public void Update(Location location)
{
    using (var context = new EfContext())
    {
        context.Locations.Attach(location);
        context.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The requirements of my application require me to attach the modified entity to a new context rather than retrieve the entity from the same context first.

This actually does work for all fields on the entity, except the LastUpdated field. It is a datetime and is not saving.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the location LastUpdated property value as parameter in Update method

```
public void Update(Location location, DateTime locationLastUpdated)
{
    using (var context = new EfContext())
    {
        location.LastUpdated = locationLastUpdated;
        context.Locations.Attach(location);
        context.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the LastUpdated value had already been set prior to the location being passed into the method. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2019889 Does it remain set after you reattach the entity and before you call `SaveChanged()`?

Comment: I understand in this specific scenario it is probably better to update the LastUpdated field in the database with a trigger and getdate() as suggested, however, this problem has the potential to occur with other DateTime fields that do not represent a database timestamp. For example, imagine if we were dealing with Person objects and we wanted to edit a Date of Birth, this would be a real problem.

Comment: In response to millimoose, I have stepped through the code with the debugger and the value is the correct datetime immediately prior to calling SaveChanges()